# Alternative to ng-init for opening bootstrap modal every time I click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my index.html:-

```
    <ul class="collapse" id="collapse">
        <li ng-click="loadDirective('menuOne')">
            <a>MENU1</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-click="loadDirective('menuTwo')">
            <a>MENU2</a>
        </li>
.... and so on
    </ul>

<modal-one ng-if="menuOne" ng-init="showModal('menuOne')"></modal-one>
<modal-two ng-if="menuTwo" ng-init="showModal('menuTwo')"></modal-two >
.... and so on
```

I am calling my custom directives when the user clicks the menu. Then showing the modal.

IndexController file:-

```
$scope.loadDirective = function(id) {
    $scope.isSidenavOpen = false;
    $scope[id] = true;
};

$scope.showModal = function(id) {
    $('#' + id).modal({
        backdrop: false,
        keyboard: false
    });
};
```

Basically, I want to call the showModal method after the directive and the HTML page loaded. Right now, I am using ng-init which is not the optimal solution for this. Is there any way in angular, I can know if HTML is loaded(like a callback)?

Comment: Are you sure about $scope[id]... $scope array?

Comment: $scope[id] = true .. $scope.id = true;

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to call this method after page gets loaded. You can make use of $window.onload = function() { };

Comment: please provide plunkr code..